# Sharepoint: List with n items, but view set to "all" shows <n?

Tags: 2010, list-view

Encountered an odd one here:

A list contains n items (roughly 3000), yet a view on said list that is set to show all items with no filter, will only display about 2980.

Any thoughts? This isn't causing any problems specifically, but it would be nice to know what could cause this discrepancy.

Also a related issue - setting a total to display on a view and saving it, yet no total is displayed, no matter what column the total is set on?

Comment: Try exporting it on excel and see the count of rows.

Comment: Also be sure you don't have any filters in place as well.

Comment: There are no filters in place, and no item limit.

Comment: Where do you see that you have more items (roughly 3000)? All Site Content page or with code?

Comment: Are there any folders in the list. They count as items. The view hower does not have to show these folders.

Comment: Hi Naim, it was found manually by counting up the total from one page to another through pagination. The list is hidden so cannot be exported.
Remko - thanks for the suggestion, but there are no folders in the list.